# Who was Rowena Ravenclaw's Heir?

Tags: harry-potter

A comment on a recent HP question indicated that we (readers) know of only 2 heirs, Slytherin's (Tom Riddle, duh) and Rowena Ravenclaw's

Who was Ravenclaw's heir? Or was that comment in jest?

Comment: You're missing a period after the first sentence. Edit is too small.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rowena Ravenclaw had a daughter named Helena Ravenclaw.

Helena was jealous of her mother and wanted to make herself more important and intelligent, and so stole her mother's prized diadem -- which was said to "enhance the wisdom of those who wore it". Upon stealing the diadem, Helena fled to Albania. While she was hiding her mother fell deathly ill. Rowena sent a Baron after her daughter, so that she could see her again before she died.

Unfortunately, that same Baron loved Helena greatly. A love Helena herself did not return. Helena refused both to return and the love offered to her by the Baron, and so the man stabbed her and took her life. Remorseful and ashamed of killing the woman he loved, the Baron then took his own life -- and later returned to Hogwarts as the ghost known only as the Bloody Baron, House ghost of Slytherin. In self-punishment for his crimes, he carries heavy chains with him.

Sometime after her death, Helena returned to Hogwarts as a ghost. She became known as the Grey Lady, House ghost of Ravenclaw. Other Houses believe that Helena never speaks, but she does in fact provide Ravenclaws with directions and information on lost belongings.

It is interesting to note that Rowena Ravenclaw never told anyone that her diadem was missing or stolen, and so everyone believed that she still had it while she was alive. It is uncertain as to when it was realized that it was "lost".

As there were no other mentions of children belonging to Rowena, and only Helena was mentioned as being of the line of Ravenclaw in the books. Therefore, it is most likely that the heir mentioned in the comment you read was Helena Ravenclaw.

Comment: Reference on the backstory?  I've not heard the specifics before

Comment: @Izkata Book 7 (Deathly Hallows), near the end, at the Hogwarts battle.

Comment: @Izkata  Book 7, the Deathly Hallows, in Chapter 31 The Battle of Hogwarts, pages 493 to 497. These pages have the conversation between Harry Potter and Helena Ravenclaw, in which Helena explains her history to Harry and gives him the clues he needs to discover where Voldemort, at that time Tom Riddle, hid the Diadem within the school. Harry deduced from this conversation that it was hidden in the Room of Requirements, from which he had emerged minutes earlier.

Comment: Ah, k.  I guess I just didn't remember part of it.

Comment: Hm... technically this is correct (a daughter is a heir), though in the context of both the HP series AND of that specific SO discussion, the implication was that heir was meant distant relative in Harry's time.

Comment: @DVK - Helena Ravenclaw is the best you're going to get. This is a really sound answer. Heir, in Potterverse, does not have to mean that, like, 1000 years separated the relatives in question. Nor do they have to be related. For example, Harry was Sirius's heir, and Harry, Ron, and Hermione were named in Dumbledore's will, which put them in an heir-like position (note that Aberforth Dumbledore was *not* named in Dumbledore's will, although Aberforth was a blood relative. My $0.02. :)

Comment: Nor does the heir need to be alive to be considered an heir...